# htaccess and encode urls

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I currently have this:

`http://site.com/image/?x=100&y=70&image=https%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Fimage.jpg`

All my yslow and google audit tells me that i can't proxy cache urls with '?' in it. So I'm changing it so that the htaccess can pass the params to my dynamic image getter, but can't figure out the htaccess. So far I have:

`http://site.com/thumb/https%3A%2F%2Fsite.com%2Fimage.jpg`

Edit, forgot the htaccess I have so far:

```
RewriteRule ^thumb/(.*)?$ image.php?a=image=$1&x=180y=70&cropratio=1:1&quality=70 [QSA,L]
```

I'm assuming it's b/c without the question mark, the browser thinks it's two urls smashed together and it's not a param.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 0):

Can you try:

```
RewriteRule ^thumb/(.*)$ /image/?image=$1&x=180y=70&cropratio=1:1&quality=70 [QSA,L,NE,NC]
```

- NE: This flag is used for not encoding the original text
- NC: For ignore case comparison

Comment: Thanks anubhava. I've been doing that and it seems like its more an issue of the PHP urlencoding slashes as %2F instead of %252F. I'm still trying to figure out a good way of doing the encoding without encoding and then having to do a string replace.